# How to register/subscribe an app user to topics in OneSignal?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, onesignal

I am using OneSignal.com platform for sending pushes.
I want to register/subscribe the app users to categories like weather, sport, technology...
There is a method in Firebase SDK:

```
Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "weather") { error in
  print("Subscribed to weather topic")
}
```

But I couldn't find the method in OneSignal.
How can I subscribe users to categories? (It can be more than one)

Answer (score 0):

OneSginal have something similar to Firebase **Topics** that are called **[Data Tags](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/add-user-data-tags)**, here is a sample java code on how to add them:

```java
class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
  // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
  @Override
  public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
    JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
    String topic;
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
    OneSignal.sendTag("last_notification_click", timestamp);

    if (data != null) {
      notification_topic = data.optString("notification_topic", null);
      if (notification_topic != null)
        OneSignal.sendTag("notification_topic", notification_topic);
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the swift code:

```swift
let notificationOpenedBlock: OSHandleNotificationActionBlock = { result in
  let payload: OSNotificationPayload? = result?.notification.payload
  let timestamp = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
  OneSignal.sendTags(["last_notification_click": timestamp])
  
    if let notification_topic = payload.additionalData?["notification_topic"] {
        OneSignal.sendTag("notification_topic", value: notification_topic)
    }
}
```

check out this [article](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/segment-based-on-notification-clicks) from OneSignal.

Comment: @uzman was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?